# SQL Procedure filepath as parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, filepath, procedure

I have the following procedure that reads json data from a file and stores it in a table. Now, I need to change it so that the filepath is a parameter. I tried, though with no luck. Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.loadData
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(max);
        SELECT @jsonVariable = BulkColumn
        FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\data.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

INSERT INTO main.jsonData(restaurant, priceRange, country, score,         
reviewDate)
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable, '$.reviews.row')
    WITH
    (
        restaurant VARCHAR(100) '$.restaurant',
        priceRange VARCHAR(50) '$.priceRange',
        country VARCHAR(50) '$.country',
        score INTEGER '$.score',
        reviewDate DATETIME '$.reviewDate'
    );  
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a filepath into the bulk statement you'll need to use dynamic SQL along these lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.loadData
@filepath varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN

Declare @script as varchar(max)

Set @script='
        DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(max);
        SELECT @jsonVariable = BulkColumn
        FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @filepath + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

INSERT INTO main.jsonData(restaurant, priceRange, country, score,         
reviewDate)
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable, ''$.reviews.row'')
    WITH
    (
        restaurant VARCHAR(100) ''$.restaurant'',
        priceRange VARCHAR(50) ''$.priceRange'',
        country VARCHAR(50) ''$.country'',
        score INTEGER ''$.score'',
        reviewDate DATETIME ''$.reviewDate''
    );'

Exec(@script)  
END;
GO
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Secondly, if I want to execute the procedure, I, of course, assume that as a parameter, I enter 'C:\data.json'. However, it's giving me an error.. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Easiest way to debug is change the "exec" to PRINT /@script or if you prefer Select /@script - then you can see what the script is and trace the error. The execution method is correct though.